# Show a warning when checking a function value instead of return value

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have been tripped up often (usually by autocomplete) when I am trying to test the value of a function return. Sometimes I forget to add the `()` at the end of it so it always returns true.

```
class Foo {
    public bar(): boolean {
        // return either true or false based on some logic
    }
}
```

```
let foo = new Foo();
if (foo.bar) {
    // UNINTENDED
    // always returns true due to "foo.bar" being a function object
}

if (foo.bar()) {
    // INTENDED
    // may return true or false depending on logic of "foo.bar"
}
```

Is there any way to be notified/warned when using the former? When debugging, it doesn't always stand out that I am missing the function call and makes it difficult to pinpoint the issue. Alternatively, is there a better way to write code to avoid this issue?

I'm using VS Code so I'm open to any possible linting that would help warn me of this issue.

Comment: You could make `bar` a property getter instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it makes senses that `bar` is used like a property getter, it might make sense to make it into one.  Doing this gives Typescript the information it needs to point out incorrect usage.

Finding a TSLint flag that does what you want might be awkward,.  As doing `if (obj.someFunction) {` is totally valid and used a lot in Javascript to test for function invocation.

Making into a property getting is not hard.

eg.

```
class test {
    get bar(): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}

var a = new test();

//This is OK.
if (a.bar) {}

//ERROR: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a 
//call signature.
if (a.bar()) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things I can think of. First, you can try using a linter. TSLint has an option called `strict-boolean-expressions` that I think will do what you want. Second, you can make a method like this into a getter.

Comment: Is there a way to apply that TSLint rule to only functions?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/), it doesn't seem so.